# Windows Spacemacs Git-gutter /tmp exception

Tags: git, emacs, windows-10, spacemacs

I have been spinning up a new machine running windows 10 and gnu emacs 26.2. After checking out the development branch, I am getting the following error when interacting with org-mode (agenda view and capture templates so far).

```
Configuring package grep...done
Configuring package projectile...done
Skipping check for new version (reason: dotfile)
Error running timer ‘global-git-gutter+-mode’: (file-missing "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!")
Configuring package helm...done (0.574s)
Configuring package evil-escape...done
Configuring package window-purpose...done (0.146s)
mwheel-scroll: Beginning of buffer [6 times]
line-move-visual: End of buffer [8 times]
Quit
```

I have tried:

1. opening git-bash and creating '/tmp'
2. uninstalling GIT and re-installing it, making it unavailable on the system path (so you have to use git-bash to avoid collisions)
3. uninstalling above GIT and installing it on the system path (so it can be used from powershell, etc)
4. clearing my .cache folder as described [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8901#issuecomment-304492105)
5. Deleting my entire .emacs.d folder and starting fresh

So far, nothing has stopped this particular error from popping up any time I try to open agenda or run a capture template.  If I checkout master branch, it works, but still gives this error.

I am unsure if this is an actual spacemacs issue or if it is just user error, which is why I am posting here instead of posting an issue on their repo just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Several months later and I have made some progress on this problem. The issue appears to be related to paths stored in the .spacemacs.env folder which is in your .spacemacs.d directory. Deleting this folder at least temporarily solves the problem.

I will update later if I find a better more permanent solution.